# How can i tell this code to redirect to the URL I want?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

I want to tell this part of code to go to the URL that I want after woocommerce registration (wordpress). It's part of an open source plugin. I know that the redirection should happen here but I don't know how to tell it to go to registration successful page. 
It goes to homepage after Woocommerce registration.

```
/*
 * This function is executed just after a new user is made from woocommerce registration form in myaccount page.
 * Its hooked into 'woocommerce_registration_redirect' filter.
 * If restrict user setting is enabled from the plugin settings screen, then this function will logs out the user.
 */

public function redirect_new_user($redirect) 
{
    if ($this->is_new_user_email_sent 
        && !XlWUEV_Common::$is_xlwuev_resend_link_clicked
        && !defined('WC_DOING_AJAX') 
        && !is_order_received_page()) 
    {
        $redirect = add_query_arg(array('xlrm' => base64_encode($this->user_id), ), $redirect);
        $is_xlwuev_restrict_user = XlWUEV_Common::get_setting_value('wuev-general-settings', 'xlwuev_restrict_user');

        if ('1' == $is_xlwuev_restrict_user) 
            wp_logout();
    }
    return $redirect;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code. Please put this code in functions.php of your active theme.

```
function iconic_register_redirect( $redirect ) {
    wp_redirect(get_the_permalink(2)); //// instead of 2 put the slug or id
    exit();
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'iconic_register_redirect' ,99,1);
```

Comment: it still redirects to homepage

Comment: Try with priority i updated the code if still it does not work than can you tell me which other plugins you are having in your system

Comment: Thanks . I put it into my theme's functions.php now I get error 500 . xxxxx.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: check now there is some syntax mistake from my side

Comment: it again goes back to main page.

Comment: My plugins are:
Adminimize   
Autoptimize 
bbpress
Cloudflare   
Contact Form Submissions   
RegistrationMagic   
Disable Cart Fragments   
Duplicate Post   
English WordPress Admin  
and in next comment --->

Comment: Force Regenerate Thumbnails   
GA Google Analytics   
Insert PHP Code Snippet   
List category posts   
Loco Translate  
Modal Survey 
Nav Menu Roles
woocommerce
Quttera Web Malware Scanner  
Slider Revolution   
Server Status   
TablePress   
TinyMCE Advanced   
UpdraftPlus - Backup/Restore   
Woocommerce Email Verification   
woocommerce membeships
Wordfence Security   
Yoast SEO Premium   
Smush  
WordPress User Extra Fields  
Yoast SEO: Local   
Yoast SEO: WooCommerce

Comment: The code I provided above is related to "Woocommerce Email Verification " which unfortunately doesn't have the Redirect option in admin panel.

Comment: Would you help please @Aki

Comment: I told you if my code is not worked for you than can you tell me which other plugins you are having in your system

Comment: I wrote them above the same day. Please have a look at our comments.

Comment: I think woocommerce membership is making the mess deactive it for while and check the same code

Comment: No SUccess even with that deactivated :(

Comment: Check with email verification on inactive that plugin

Comment: tried some more and your suggestion still no suceess. but by deactivating "email verification" plugin, I was redirected to my-account page instead of home page. so it should be this plugin.

Comment: So that plugin is changing the redirection am i right ?

Comment: First thanks for your comment. Second, Absolutely right. The link to the plugin: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-confirmation-email/
Download Link:
https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/woo-confirmation-email.3.1.15.zip

Comment: go to the plugin directory and click on public folder than comment 40 line no and active the plugin and than try my code and pass the correct page id in my code.

Comment: I didn't get exactly what you mean. I commented out line 40 using // but it again went to the home page. So please let me know what to do with this. 
This is the line 40:

      add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', array( $this, 'redirect_new_user' ) );

And this is how I use your code(please confirm it is correct):

function iconic_register_redirect( $redirect ) {
    wp_redirect(get_the_permalink(emailverification)); 
    exit();
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'iconic_register_redirect' ,99,1);

Thanks a million!

Comment: Yes that is also fine.

Comment: Any idea @Aki ?

Comment: create a group over the stackoverflow it took long comment

Comment: it seems I can't because of my rep level